# typeerror: app.use() requires middleware function fix

Tags: javascript

I am creating an e-commerce website with Mern. These are the early stages. While following a lecture when professor run npm run dev starts while mine pops up an error indicating app.use requires middleware function It says the [nodemon] app crushed: I have tried matching code and its same. Please help me to resolve the error I have been stuck here for hours tried a lot of edits but it's not working for me.

```js
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const cors = require('cors')
const fileupload = require('express-fileupload')
const cookieParser = require('cookieParser')


const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(cors())
app.use(fileupload({
    useTempFiles: true
}))

// connect to mongodb
const URI = process.env.MONGODB_URL
mongoose.connect(URI, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, err =>{
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
})


app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.json({msg: "Welcome to AcesDesigns, please enjoy our services. Thanks"})
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT, () =>{
    console.log('Server is running on port', PORT)
})
```

Here Is the code. Server.js

And the Error message in the Terminal is as follows

```js
$ npm run dev

> ecommerce@1.0.0 dev C:\Users\EVA MWASHIGADI\Ecommerce
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json  
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
C:\Users\EVA MWASHIGADI\Ecommerce\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:210
    throw new TypeError('app.use() requires a middleware function')
    ^
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Which package is that for the `cookieParser`? You might be looking for [`require('cookie-parser')`](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser) instead. The error indicates you're not passing a valid function to `app.use()`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the right cookie-parser package? Isn't it

```
require('cookie-parser')
```

This is the only place I think you would face a problem